# How do I call the method of a derived class from a list that contains parent objects?

Tags: c#

I am making a game that has an inventory system.  The inventory system can contain any *WorldObject*.  There are a number of derived classes from *WorldObject* that will be held within the inventory.

```
public class WorldObject
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod();
}

public class Weapon : WorldObject
{
    public override void SomeMethod();
}

public class Tool: WorldObject
{
    public override void SomeMethod();
}
```

and the inventory:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public List<WorldObject> ObjectList;

    public Inventory()
    {
        ObjectList = new List<WorldObject>();
    }

    public void AddToInventory(WorldObject object)
    {
        ObjectList.Add(object);
    }

    public void Foo(int itemIndex)
    {
        Weapon weaponObject = ObjectList[itemIndex] as Weapon;
        if(weaponObject != null)
        {
            weaponObject.SomeMethod();
        }
        else
        {
            Tool toolObject = ObjectList[itemIndex] as Tool;
            if(toolObject != null)
            {
                toolObject.SomeMethod();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, is there a better way to call the child methods on each of my items?  This seems like a lot of headache as my game gets larger.  Having 10+ different ways to do the same thing seems wrong.

Comment: Why not just `ObjectList[itemIndex].SomeMethod();`

Comment: You don't need the ifs, [virtual methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) will work exactly in the way that you need.

Comment: Well I feel dumb now :P  Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's why `SomeMethod` is virtual, you know? So simply:

```
WorldObject obj = ObjectList[itemIndex];
obj.SomeMethod();
```

will do what you want — call the override of `SomeMethod` in the correct ancestor.

You can [read the basics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) on Wikipedia, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I totally missed that that was the entire point of virtual...

Comment: I'm glad it's shining some light on the topic for  you.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to call this method in this way:

```
ObjectList[itemIndex].SomeMethod();
```

And correct your WorldObject class to

```
public class WorldObject
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod() {}
}
```

or

```
public abstract class WorldObject
{
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: @BenN No, if you remove the `virtual` keyword, you will get a compilation error.

Comment: @BenN Either virtual or abstract is required. For virtual methods OP has to provide implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SomeMethod` is virtual, just call it on the object you get from `ObjectList[itemIndex]`. C# will call the base (no-op) method if the object is just a `WorldObject`, or the appropriate override of it if the object is one of the derived classes. [Read about polymorphism on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)